# Is there a way to make portable file creation?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to make a C++ function that creates a file called `log.txt` in the same directory as the binary and outputs data.

When I use `ofstream` it creates the file where the source code is.

If I move the binary to a different directory it doesn't create any file.

Code:

```cpp
ofstream logFile("log.txt");
void print(string msg)
{
    if (USING_DEBUG == true) {
        cout << "Log: " << msg;
    }
    logFile << "Log: " << msg;
}
```

Comment: ***If I move the binary to a different directory it doesn't create any file.*** It won't if you don't have write permissions in that different directory.

Comment: @drescherjm I moved it to a directory I have permissions in though. I don't know how C++ handles relative paths so maybe that is the issue but I don't know.

Comment: ***in the same directory as the binary***, ***`ofstream logFile("log.txt");`*** You should know about a current working directory, that can differ from the executable's directory.

Comment: @273K That's not my point, how do I get it to work? Does it point to the working directory? How can I make it portable so it can create the file from any location?

Comment: There is no such a portable way. Moreover, a directory of an executable normally is read-only. Most users got used to work with admin privileges on Windows, that is not a good practice.

Comment: There is no portable way to do as you have described.   To obtain executable path (the directory containing the executable) the means are host (operating system) specific.   From C++17, it is possible to obtain or set the working directory (location where your program opens file at runtime, and where relative paths are referred to) using `std::filesystem::current_path()` [although there are various caveats].

Comment: You will never be 100% portable. There are file systems in use that have no directories, and that don't support extensions on file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse `argv[0]` get the directory of the executable relative to the current working directory at startup.  This should be reasonable for what you want. Then append "log.txt" and attempt to open the file at that path.

So if argv[0] passed in simply `foo.exe` or `foo` without a path qualifier, then you'd open a `log.txt` file without an explicit path. If argv[0] is something like `../project/bin`, then you'd open a log file at `../project/log.txt`.  If it's something like `c:\users\selbie\foo.exe`, then you'd open `c:\users\jselbie\log.txt`

Some code below that makes an attempt at this.

```
bool openLogFile(const std::string& argv0, std::ofstream& logFile)
{
#if WIN32 || _WIN32
    const char delimiter = '\\';
#else
    const char delimiter = '/';
#endif

    std::string directory;
    std::string logFilePath;

    // get the directory of argv[0], if any
    size_t index = argv0.find_last_of(delimiter);
    if (index != std::string::npos)
    {
        directory = argv0.substr(0, index+1); // +1 to include the delimiter
    }

    logFilePath = directory + "log.txt";

    std::cout << "opening log file at: " << logFilePath << " ";

    logFile.open(logFilePath.c_str());
    bool success = logFile.is_open();

    std::cout << (success ? "succeeded" : "failed") << "\n";

    if (success)
    {
        logFile << "First log file line\n";
    }

    return success;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::ofstream logFile;
    openLogFile(argv[0], logFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why implement this yourself instead of just using `std::filesystem::path`? `auto logFilePath = std::filesystem::canonical(argv[0]).parent_path() / "log.txt"; logFile.open(logFilePath);`???

Comment: "You can parse argv[0]" You also need to handle `$PATH` or `%PATH%` or whatever your system has to search for executables.

Comment: `argv[0]` is not guaranteed to be the path to the executable. On linux you should instead read the `/proc/self/exe` symlink - other platforms have other platform specific ways to get the executable path but they all differ between Solaris, AiX, HPUX, *BSD, VMS, Windows etc.